# hide parent div when clicking it but not it's child div

Tags: jquery, html

I have something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to hide **parent div** when I click on it, but not when I click on **child div**

I have something like this:

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
  $('this').hide();
});
```

any ideas?
maybe it's a silly question but I can't figure out how to do it, if someone knows that I'll be grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
$('this').hide();
});

$("#child").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can check http://jsfiddle.net/lnanikian/f3qar/

Comment: Update your Jquery lib maybe

Answer (score 0):

using jquery and the below script the desired result can be achieved

```
<script>
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var  child = $("#child");
if (! child.is(e.target)&&  childr.has(e.target).length === 0)
{
    child.hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
  $('#child', $(this)).hide();
});
```

Or

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
  $(this).find('#child').hide();
});
```